# poque no puedo ver python2web si no lo meto en un bucle;

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var python2web = new Array();
var texto;
function peticion(){

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        python2web = xhr.responseText;
    }
    xhr.open("get","python2web",true);
    xhr.send();
}
setInterval(peticion,1000/100);
```

Si imprimo en consola lo que hay en python2web me sale undefined

```
console.log(python2web);
```

Sin embargo si lo hago con un bucle sale el texto correspondiente

```
function mostrar(){
    console.log(python2web);
}
setInterval(python2web,1000/100);`
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Cuando se termina de ejecutar `peticion()` aún no tienes la respuesta porque es una llamada asíncrona

Comment: y que hago para solucionar eso no quiero tener que meter la variable en un bucle cada vez que quiero hacer algo con el texto que hay dentro